# iPython wx support?

Tags: wxpython, ipython

This question is very similar to one I recently asked: [Python threading- returning control to the terminal while keeping a frame open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888127/python-threading-returning-control-to-the-terminal-while-keeping-a-frame-open) except I'd like to know how to use iPython interactively with wxPython.

For example, I'd like this little script to return control to the terminal after it's opened up a frame:

```
from wxPython.wx import *

class MyApp(wxApp):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = wxFrame(NULL, -1, "Hello from wxPython")
        frame.Show(true)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return true

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Using "ipython -pylab" works brilliantly with plt.show() but it does not return control to the terminal with frame.Show(True).

I understand that iPython 0.11 will have a magic interface for this, but what are people using to have an interactive session with wxPython in the meantime?

Thanks!
--Erin

Comment: Did you try the `-wthread` and `-wxversion` commandline options to IPython?

Comment: Yes, I have. Neither return control to the terminal in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few modifications to the script needed to be made:

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Hello from wxPython")
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Note the difference in how wx is imported- the rest of the changes just support the newer statement. Run with ipython -pylab -wthread and it works fine :)