# IPython on wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, ipython

I have been trying to find a way to have an IPython Shell in an `wx.Frame`.

Searching around in the library code or  Google

- [wxPython based IPython widget](https://www.google.com/search?q=wxPython%20based%20IPython%20widget)
- [ipython shell wxpython](https://www.google.com/search?q=ipython%20shell%20wxpython)

haven't helped me much either.

Is there any widget that IPython provides that can be used with wx, to integrate an IPython shell into my `Frame`??

Comment: All I can find is [this](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython). Assuming it's only capable of reading/writing from stdin/stdout, then you can change `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` to file-like objects which redirect I/O from some native widget in wxPython.

Comment: @Aya Yes, it is a good article, but I don't see how I can redirect the I/O as wx, "overshadows"(might not be the right word) the `sys.std*` vars, and uses it's own. So,(to me) it seems the only way is to give input and get output from the IPython Library..

Comment: You can disable that behavior in wxPython by using the `redirect` parameter when you create the `wx.App` object with something like: `my_app = wx.App(redirect=False)`, which is also really convenient when debugging application startup errors if you're running your script from a console window.

Answer (score 0):

According to the IPython docs, there is a wxPython frontend:

- http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/install/install.html

However, I can't really tell if that's what you want, so here are a few links on embedding IPython in wxPython:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wxPython-dev/lBOSXTaY2ZQ
- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/lib/ipkernel_wxapp.py
- [iPython wx support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979327/ipython-wx-support)

wxPython also has it's own shell called PyCrust / PyShell that you can see in the wxPython demo package.

Comment: The wxPython frontend was dropped with the big reorganisation in 0.11, and 0.10 is old now. There's still support for the Wx event loop (so you can run a Wx GUI without blocking IPython), but there's no longer a ready-made widget for a shell in Wx.

Comment: The release numbering has been a bit conservative - the code reorganisation in 0.11 was more like a major version increment. I mentally divide our releases into 'classic IPython' and 'modern IPython', i.e. 0.11 and above.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll *Note: I had visited these links(except the script one)*  About the links: **1.** IPython 0.10 is old.. **2.** 2009 ?? **3.** :) That is nice. **4.** That is on running a wx app and still having control of the shell.

Comment: Okay, well I think I'm out of suggestions then. You might want to cross post to the wxPython users group